# Return Custom Response based off Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, error-handling, fluentvalidation

I've got some error messages as part of my validation setup. How would I go about returning a particular json response instead of the standard json response returned by my fluent validation.

How I've implemented my class:

```
public class CafeRequestValidator : AbstractValidator<CafeGetRequest>
    {
        public CafeRequestValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.MaxDistance).GreaterThan(0).WithMessage("Non-Negative distance required");
            RuleFor(x => x.SortOrder).NotNull().WithMessage("Please sort by desc or asc");
        }
    }
```

Current Response when an error is triggered:

```
{
    "isValid": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "propertyName": "MaxDistance",
            "errorMessage": "Non-Negative distance required",
            "attemptedValue": -1000,
            "customState": null,
            "severity": 0,
            "errorCode": "GreaterThanValidator",
            "formattedMessageArguments": [],
            "formattedMessagePlaceholderValues": {
                "ComparisonValue": 0,
                "ComparisonProperty": "",
                "PropertyName": "Max Distance",
                "PropertyValue": -1000
            },
            "resourceName": null
        }
    ],
    "ruleSetsExecuted": [
        "default"
    ]
}
```

Expected response:

```
error : {
message : "Non-Negative distance required",
code : -10123 /* For internal tracking of source */
}*/
}
```